# Чтение данных из SQLite3 DB C#

Tags: база-данных, entity-framework, linq, sqlite3

Работаю на C# с DB SQLite 3. Написал небольшую программу, для считывания нужных данных из данной DB. При компиляции в VS 2017 , вес билда небольшой, но Dll для x64 и для x86 вешают почти 4 мб!

Есть ли альтернативы данной библиотеки с маленьким весом?

Перебрал много библиотек, никто не может считать данные с SQLite 3 DB.
Ищу и пробую каждую библиотеку 4 дня, в интернете нет ответов на данный вопрос. Заранее всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот такую пробывали: [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/)

Вот запрос:

```
public class SqlHandler
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public IEnumerable<SqlHandler> 
        GetHandlerName(IEnumerable<SqlHandler> sqlHandler, 
        String name) => 
        sqlHandler
        .Where(x => x
        .Name
        .Equals(name))
        .Select(x => x);
}
```

Comment: пробовал ,много лишних Dll с большим весом. Нашел C# класс, с помощью которого можно читать DB SQLite 3, но загвоздка в том, что не могу понять как написать запрос для этого класса.                        .....https://dropmefiles.com/Laks5 вот сам класс,  если кто разберется , то отпишите сформировать запрос

Comment: @Bortman, думаю запрос Вам подойдет!)

Comment: если через этот класс: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847337/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-c вы хотите работать с базой, то лучше начать ORM EF осваивать)

Comment: в той теме почти разобрались, я  нашел нужный класс, он считывает с БД нужные данные. Но пока не могу получить эти данные, приложение консольное, при запуске билда, в консоле только мигает курсор и все на этом(

Comment: ORM хорошая штука, но в моем случае ее не использовать

Comment: Почему? Опишите тогда конкретней задачу

Comment: нужно получить данные с DB SQLite3, не использую SQLite библиотеки, нашел класс, который разбивает БД по байтам и оттуда вытягивает нужные данные, но он зависает при получении данных из таблицы, уходя в бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Почему так привязались к этому классу, есть многу других выходов.

Comment: посоветуйте выход, только на SQLite библиотеки

Comment: Используйте sqllite provider + ef

Comment: уже разобрался с классом, все работает)